# how run ionic cordova run android?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

in project type
ionic cordova run android

The error message is :

```
Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
For input string: "+"
```

The code in cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle is :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
```

}

The code in project.properties is :

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/cordova_plugin_firebase-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-support-google-services/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=phonegap-plugin-multidex/cordova_plugin_firebase-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.10=com.android.support:support-v13:27.+
cordova.system.library.11=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2
```

Where is the problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-firebase
change The code cordova_plugin_firebase-build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
       transitive = true
    }
}

cdvPluginPostBuildExtras.add({
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
})
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

..\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services
and change The code is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
ext.postBuildExtras = {
   // apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

and change

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/cordova_plugin_firebase-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1      
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.4
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-support-google-services/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=phonegap-plugin-multidex/cordova_plugin_firebase-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.10=com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1
cordova.system.library.11=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my cordova project, Try to crosscheck the compatibility of plugin you using specially Push-Plugin with Google Play Services(User 1.1.0 version) , If you can share plugin version i can help more. Try to use following version, it fixed my issue. And don't include dependency multiple rimes check 6 and 12.

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
```

Comment: cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"

Comment: Please provide full plugin list you using in your application.

Comment: cordova-android-support-gradle-release 2.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.0.1 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.4.2 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"

Comment: cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.5.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"

Comment: Looks fine for me try to change dependency in plugin file and project properties for Firebase-messaging to 15.0.2. and try rebuilding. If failed try to use fix version rather using '+' in google service like com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager

Comment: Most welcome dear, it took me 2 days to solve it. Please mark as answer if it solved your issue. Thanks.